# Cart Message for a Specific Shipping Class in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, notice

I'm trying to add a cart message for a specific shipping class. Adapted from [Cart Message for a specific shipping class and a minimal cart total in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923326/cart-message-for-a-specific-shipping-class-and-a-minimal-cart-total-in-woocommer/51219275#51219275) answer, this is my code attempt:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cart_items_shipping_class_message', 20, 1 );
function cart_items_shipping_class_message( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;
    
    $shipping_class = '150';
   
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() === $shipping_class ){
        wc_clear_notices();
                
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Beers can only be shipped via <a title="Pallet Shiping" href="/shipping-delivery/#Pallet_Shipping" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Pallet Shiping</a>. To reveal much cheaper UPS Shipping Rates, remove Beers from the Cart.'), 'notice' );
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it seems that you have defined **a shipping class Id** in your question code, so you need to use the `WC_Product` `get_shipping_class_id()` method instead as follow:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cart_items_shipping_class_message', 20, 1 );
function cart_items_shipping_class_message( $cart ){

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $shipping_class_id = '150'; // Your shipping class Id

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // Check cart items for specific shipping class, displaying a notice
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_id ){
            wc_clear_notices();
            wc_add_notice( sprintf(
                __('Beers can only be shipped via %s. To reveal much cheaper UPS Shipping Rates, remove Beers from the Cart.', 'woocommerce'),
                '<a title="Pallet Shipping" href="/shipping-delivery/#Pallet_Shipping" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">' . __("Pallet Shipping", "woocommerce") . '</a>'
            ), 'notice' );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

---

**Addition:** To display the notice only on cart page, replace the following code:

```
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
```

by this:

```
    if ( ! is_cart() || ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) )
        return;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works perfectly.

However, this notice does not show when another notice is displayed in the cart. 

Is it possible to display two notices in the cart?

Comment: I figured it out. I had wc_clear_notices(); on the other snippet.

Comment: It seems that the woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook adds the message on the cart and checkout page. Is there a way to only show the message on the cart page? I tried using the "woocommerce_before_cart" hook but it creates a Fatal error:

Comment: @WanderlustConsulting I have added an addition at the end of the answer for that.