# WooCommerce checkout display a message based on specific shipping class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I would like to set a message to specific shipping class in Woocommerce checkout page.

I tried using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'cart_items_shipping_class_message', 20, 1 );
function cart_items_shipping_class_message( $cart ){

    $shipping_class_id = 14; // Your shipping class Id

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // Check cart items for specific shipping class, displaying a notice
        //if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_id ){
            var_dump($cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id());
            echo "Do poznámky k objednávce napište adresu Zásilkovny nebo ZBoxu, kam chcete objednávku doručit.";
            //break;
        //}
    } 
}
```

But when I try to `var_dump` selected shipping class, it always returns me `int(0)`.

I have used something similar to: [Cart Message for a Specific Shipping Class in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928328/cart-message-for-a-specific-shipping-class-in-woocommerce/63928723#63928723), because It did not work for me.

Comment: Your code works for me. Try following @LoicTheAztec's suggestion in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *[Cart Message for a Specific Shipping Class in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928328/cart-message-for-a-specific-shipping-class-in-woocommerce/63928723#63928723)* answer still works on last woocommerce version.

Your question code works and display the shipping class Id… So there is something else that is making trouble.

**Be sure that a cart item has the required shipping class set for it.**

Try following to display a message in checkout based for specific shipping class **slug**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'checkout_shipping_class_message' );
function checkout_shipping_class_message(){
    // Here your shipping class slugs in the array
    $shipping_classes = array('truck');
    // Here your shipping message
    $message = __("Please add some shipping details in order notes field.", "woocommerce");

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $shipping_class = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class();
        
        // echo '<pre>' . print_r($shipping_class, true) . '</pre>'; // Uncomment for testing

        // Check cart items for specific shipping class, displaying a message
        if( in_array($shipping_class, $shipping_classes ) ){
            echo '<tr class="shipping-note">
                <td colspan="2"><strong>'.__("Note", "woocommerce").':</strong> '.$message.'</td>
            </tr>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.